# Login to any website with python request?

Tags: python, authentication, request

I'm trying to implement the following working code:

```
header = {
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
}

login_data = {
 'strUserName': 'myUserName',
 'strPassword': '******',
 'go': 'GO'
}
mUrl = 'https://insight.skybitz.com/CheckAccess'
with requests.Session() as s:
  url = mUrl
  login = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=header)
  print('you signed in to www.skybitz.com with status code: ' + str(login.status_code))
  print(login.content)
```

Chrome inspections for skybitz.com are:
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyvYn.png) and [Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65pVl.png)

How does this look like for following website?
Now I am trying to login to website which has different Form Data:
[Form Data of another website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMETR.png)

I tried replace items of login_data with:

```
login_data = {
  'appActionToken': 'js2tMiWmHAAAAAAAAAAUMwj3D',
  'appAction': 'SIGNIN',
  'openid.return_to': 'ape:aHR0cHM6LyHBBBBBBBBVWF6b24uY29tLw==',
  'prevRID': 'ape:ape:N1FXVSCCCCCCCCCUpLRzA=',
  'workflowState': 'eyJ6aXADDDDDDDDlbmMiOi',
  'email': 'example@example.com',
  'create': '0',
  'password': '*******',
  'metadata1': 'ECdITeCs:jHyq0VWAl0Hb3zBp2JvsEagN5r3l3yT0EiTDbU7',
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? or workflowState and metadata1 are bcrypted?

Answer (score 0):

What a server response in second case?  And what about cookies? I think, you need to check it by Chrome and set it in your `header`